# Using Parse master key from the server and not cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

I recently implemented the security of my Parse app thinking that I could use the master key on my server (express not cloud code) to securely bypass my security implementations for admin/server level functions.

I'm using "parse": "^1.5.0",
in my package.json.

Right now in each of my express modules I have:

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
Parse.initialize("Application ID", "Javascript Key", "Master Key");
```

Everything works fine without CLPs activated but with CLPs I can't do any read/write of the data with the server.  I understand that I can move this to Cloud code and get it to work however I need to use a number of libraries in my code that Parse does not support and transporting all of the code to cloud code would be very tough.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could CLPs be knocking out the master key on the server?

Comment: Why is it so quiet in SO these days? Did I miss something? It used to be quite a bit more active place.

Comment: It should work with the master key. Have you tried to update your package via `npm` to the latest version ?

Comment: @MoNazemi, I did update npm to version 1.6.3.  Still it isn't working.  I must be missing something simple and idiosyncratic. Do you have a sample implementation you could point me to?  Or maybe you could send me a snippet of code to cut in paste.  Am I putting it in the right place? I'm using Angular Fullstack and I require and initialize Parse in each JS directory where my server side code is.  Maybe it should be done another way?

Comment: Have you seen this http://blog.parse.com/learn/using-node-js-with-parse/  ?

Comment: @MoNazemi Thanks for the suggestion but I have read exactly this article and I'm not sure that's the best fix for my issue as it would require me to rewrite a massive amount of code to fit into a ClodeCode format.  Furthermore, my issue is directly with the master key, something that goes completely unmentioned in the article.  Any other suggestions addressing the master key head on? https://www.parse.com/questions/masterkey-in-nodejs this link takes me to the suggestion on how to use the master key that isn't working for me.

Comment: I quickly looked at the Parse Javascript SDK source code and it seems even if you initialise it with your master key, it is not going to grant you the privileges unless you call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` explicitly in your code before calling a query. As far as the source code shows, `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` is clearly available for Node.js

Comment: @MoNazemi - wow, really? I did not know that thanks!  I tried to implement that by calling it right under Parse.Initialize.  That didn't work. How/where do implement Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); on the server?

Comment: They implemented it using this `CoreManager.set('USE_MASTER_KEY', true);`

Comment: I think I just got it to work by calling it inside my exports.create function! Thanks for the help you have my major appreciation!

Comment: No problem. Make sure to post what you did as an answer. Might be useful to someone in future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

/////////////////////////////////this is the top of the JS page/module/////

```
'use strict';
var Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize('app-id','js-key','master-key');

exports.create = function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    //now when you do a parse query or action you can bypass your security settings.
};
```

Comment: Realised that you need to call Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); in every function you're using Parse queries instead. eg. Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); doesn't work when you put it below or above Parse.initialize().

Comment: @NurImanIzam, I'm not clear on what you mean, so I shouldn't use Parse.initialize()? I should only use Parse.Cloud.userMasterKey() everywhere?

Comment: You still have to Parse.initialize('app-id','js-key','master-key'); once at the top of your file. but Parse.Cloud.userMasterKey() was needed in every function(req,res) { .. } I had.